# Using range for ChartObject only works once? VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-chart

I am trying to create two PivotCharts on two separate worksheets within an Excel file using vba. I am using a range of a chart object to place the pivot charts where I want them. This method is only working for one of the PivotCharts and it is the second one in the code.

I tried looking this up but the only errors with this I can find online is a data range error and this is not the issue as far as I can tell...

```
Dim pivotchart_bar As Chart
Dim chart_rng As Range

Set chart_rng = Range("C10:G35")

With chart_rng
    Set pivotchart_bar = ws3.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height).Chart
End With

With pivotchart_bar
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 188, 255)
    .SeriesCollection(2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 219, 51)
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Caption = "=ws3!B1"
End With
```

The above code DOES NOT put the chart in the range C10:G35. 
The below code DOES put the chart in the range B10:F35, which is correct. They are two charts on two different worksheets but the code should be nearly identical.

```
Dim pivotchart_donut As Chart
Dim chart_rng_2 As Range

Set chart_rng_2 = Range("B10:F35")

With chart_rng_2
    Set pivotchart_donut = ws4.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height).Chart
End With

With pivotchart_donut
.ChartType = xlDoughnut
.ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlDataLabelsShowPercent
End With
```

I have tried making a new sheet and I have played with the range and I'm still not sure what the issue is. I've been playing with this for a week without any results... Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Does any line throw an error?

Comment: No, the complete code runs fine and returns no error. The only problem in the whole code (that I know of) is just that the first pivot chart does not go where I tell it to.

Comment: Where does the chart get put then?

Comment: It seems random. I put the data in a completely new file and copy/pasted the macro there and the first time the chart just showed up in a random spot in the sheet. I moved it with the mouse and then when I ran the code again the chart didn't move. The code deletes the sheet if it's there and makes a new one.

Comment: Maybe I should also mention that the codes are in the same Sub and in sequential order within the code so the first chart to be made does not work and the second chart made does work.

Comment: Reference the ranges to the worksheets: `Set chart_rng = ws3.Range("C10:G35")` and `Set chart_rng_2 = ws4.Range("B10:F35")`

Comment: This worked!! So silly... thank you!!